# Comparar color de TextView en android studio

Tags: android, color

Cómo puedo comparar el color de un TextView con algún color de mi colors.xml

Algo así como esta comparación de background pero con el color del texto

```
if ( relajado.background.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx,R.drawable.bg_rectangle_no_selected)!!.constantState)
```

Comment: Hola, que quieres comparar el color del background o del texto?

Comment: El del textview, el código que he puesto del background es a modo de ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer con el textview

Comment: ya te respondi :D, he modificado la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay que obtener el color en formato `decimal` con una fórmula:

Para el color del TextView:

```
 int colorText = textView.getCurrentTextColor();
 int colorDecimalText = (colorText)+(16777215+1);
```

Para obtener el decimal de algun color que este en recursos (colors.xml):

```
 int colorRecurso = getResources().getColor(R.color.tuColor);
 int colorDecimalRecurso = (colorRecurso)+(16777215+1);
```

De esta forma se obtiene el color en `decimal` que lo puedes
convertir a `Hex` en sitios web como: https://convertingcolors.com/decimal-color-8532459.html
`Hex` es el formato de color en colors.xml.
La fórmula +(16777215+1) se usa porque 
toma de base el color blanco, que se le resta al primer int.

O bien usar este código para convertirlo a Hex:

```
String hexColorText = "#" + Integer.toHexString(colorText).substring(2);
String hexColorRec = "#" + Integer.toHexString(colorRecurso).substring(2);
```

Para comparar en `decimal`:

```
 if(colorDecimalText == colorDecimalRecurso){
      ... tu código
    }
```

Para comparar como `String`(Hex):

```
  if(hexColorText.equals(hexColorRec)){
     ... tu código   
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

si quieres comparar el background del textView seria de la siguiente manera.

```
if (textView.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable) {
   ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground();
   if(cd.getColor()==(int)Color.GREEN){
      //Tu logica
   }
}
```

Si quieres comparar el color del texto del textView seria de la siguiente manera.

```
if(textView.getCurrentTextColor()==(int)Color.GREEN){  //textView es tu textView 
   //Tu logica
}
```

Saludos.